# Default render color vector for fragment shader when using a frame buffer with multiple attachment?

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, framebuffer, webgl2

ChatGPT insists that when using a framebuffer and attaching multiple draw buffers, the 0-indexed one will be the one that when you write to in the shader, it will be rendered on the canvas. However I don't find it to be the case.

Here's how I setup:

```
   // Create and bind framebuffer
    multiFrameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, multiFrameBuffer);

    // Create textures for color attachments
    const textureRender = createTexture(gl);
    const textureSmoothed = createTexture(gl);
    const textureWithChangeMarks = createTexture(gl);

    // Attach textures to framebuffer
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureRender, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureSmoothed, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureWithChangeMarks, 0);

    // Specify draw buffers
    gl.drawBuffers([
        gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
        gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2
    ]);
```

in my fragment shader I define:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 mergedColor;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 changedColor;
```

I write colors to all vectors, I expect that writing to `fragColor` will be the rendered pixels on the canvas associated with the webgl context, but nothing renders.
If I `readPixels` from the other two - I get the buffer as expected.
I haven't tried to read like that from `attachment0` - but I'd like to be able to directly render to the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do either, render to a framebuffer or render to the canvas (the default framebuffer). Afaik the default framebuffer (bound when calling `gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)`) can not be configured outside the arguments given during context creation, meaning it'll always have one and only one color attachment.

If you're using webgl2 you can use `blitFramebuffer` to copy the contents from your `READ_FRAMEBUFFER` to your `DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`, using the `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` this will copy the contents of your first color attachment to the canvas. In WebGL1 you'd need to draw a screenspace rectangle and manually blit the texture using a simple fragment shader.

Comment: When trying the `blitFramebuffer` approach, I get: `GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Invalid operation on multisampled framebuffer` error. ChatGPT recommends creating a "intermediate" frame buffer, binding the texture, and copying from it - but I still get the error when I try it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934444/webgl-framebuffer-multisampling